# Customizing Action Bar

Tags: android

I try to customize the ActionBar. Here is my attempt: [image]

I overlayed the background and I would like to overlay bottom border and disable drop shadow under Action Bar.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <bitmap
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_bg"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>

</layer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer to this [url](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) , i think it helps to you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Bottom Line -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
             // you can change here
            <solid android:color="@color/action_bar_line_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Color of your action bar -->
    <item android:bottom="2dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/action_bar_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I've checked it, but there is used the same way. I'm not able overlay bottom border according to this way.